# Xamarin.Forms MVVM getting responce from DIsplayAlert

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

How to work with `DisplayAlert()` correctly from MVVM view?

I have some screen and ViewModel for it. 
Inside the ViewModel I defined some `Actions`:

```
class PageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Action DisplayDataSavedPromt;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public ICommand SaveCommand { protected set; get; }

    public PageViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSubmit);
    }

    public void OnSubmit()
    {           
        DisplayDataSavedPromt();
    }

}
```

And then I'm calling it from View `Page.cs`:

```
public Page ()
{
    var vm = new PageViewModel();
    this.BindingContext = vm;
    vm.DisplayDataSavedPromt += () => DisplayAlert("Success", "Your data are saved", "OK");
    InitializeComponent ();
}
```

And it's working fine, but I can't understand how can I bind some actions to this Alert's buttons? 
E.g. when user clicks OK inside Alert, open new page.

Should I do it inside `ViewModel` somehow or inside View?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this in your view model

```
var res = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Success", "Your data are saved", "Ok", "Cancel");

if(res){//logic} else {//logic}
```

Comment: With small fixes it's working as intended now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to await the user action, and then parse the result, like this:

```
var result = await DisplayAlert("Success", "Your data are saved", "Ok", "Cancel"); 

//User pressed OK
if(result == true) 
{
    // do your logic
}
else // User pressed Cancel
{ 
    // do your logic
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I get the point, but where should I put it? Inside View or ViewModel?

Comment: In the code-behind class (view.xaml.cs) , since it is a Interface oriented method.

Comment: How can I bind it to my ViewModel? I mean the similar way I have it now - `vm.DisplayDataSavedPromt`. If I just write `DisplayAlert` without ViewModel, it's not going to work I guess.

Comment: Why do you want to Bind to your viewmodel? you can simple, in the result, change the properties you want in your viewmodel.

Comment: Because I have logic inside ViewModel. E.g. if some parameter equals smth, call `DisplayDataSavedPromt`. Could you please expand your answer somehow, so I can understand how to make it right?

Comment: @Alex You can try                                                                          var res = await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(Success", "Your data are saved", "Ok", "Cancel");