# Best practice for choosing handler or command for the button in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin. By learning the MVVM pattern, I've got the idea for mapping button with commands, and deal with logical things in viewmodel.

Then scenarios changed. 
When I was developing some Login functionalities for the mobile app, I need to call **"DisplayAlert"** or **"pop"** or **"push"** when clicking the button.

I checked some forums and blogs to see how to solve, listed as below:

1. pass the navigation as a parameter, like [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21822/call-navigation-pushasync-from-viewmodel), or even use injection in the same thread;
2. use NuGet packages like [userdialogs](https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs)
3. use handler like [Microsoft docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/LoginFlow/), (so I assumed that it is acceptable to use handler in simple navigation).
4. add some message text in viewmodel class and mapping to some entries on the view, but this cannot solve the conflict when it is required for a dialog box or navigation.

So is this question supposed to change to "how to choose button implementation, handler or command"?

But again, "handler" is not recommended by MVVM. Now I am confused.

Any advice will be helpful.

Cheers.

Comment: Bind the command to button. this will help you.

Comment: #4 is the way to go, still don't understand what conflicts are you talking about.. Is this question about how to present a dialog from viewmodel?..

Comment: Actually, #4 is I figured out by myself, but still need a choice when presenting a dialog.

Comment: Thanks, Jaymin and Nick, actually I know how to "complete" these things as the link I listed, but what I was confused is that how to choose between handler and command, like any guideline or best practice. Cheers

Comment: Update, alternatively, could call from App.MainPage, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52517281/xamarin-forms-mvvm-getting-responce-from-displayalert)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though you have used MVVM .Use command is better because it will break the standard of MVVM (we should handle the logic in ViewModel as soon as possible) if you use click event in code behind.

You can handle the logic in ViewModel and pass params in xaml .

For example , if you want pass the content page and get the navigation in ViewModel

> in xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Name="MainContentPage"
             x:Class="xxx.MainPage">

//...

 <Button Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ButtonClickCommand , Source={x:Reference MainContentPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="xxx"/>
...
```

> in ViewModel

```
ButtonClickCommand = new Command(
            (parameter) =>
            {
                var page = parameter as ContentPage;
               // do something you want
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a new idea for me to pass the parameters via command. I'll take a try.

Comment: Your code is one of the solutions, so voted for useful, cheers. Actually, I was looking for some suggestion, rather than some code snippets, hope someone could give more info.